# How to remove addresses from Thunderbird's autocomplete drop-down?

Tags: thunderbird, autocomplete

When Thunderbird suggests email addresses for me as I type, there are many addresses there that I know are obsolete.  How can I permanently remove them so they are never suggested to me again?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

[image: Address Book]

1. Open the Address Book.
2. Select **Collected Addresses**.
3. Select the entries to delete.
4. Type <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete the entries.

Ensure no explicit entries for the obsolete email address exist in **Personal Address Book**.

Comment: how to open the address book? nothing obvious anywhere :( -- nm, i found `cd /Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/MacOS

./thunderbird-bin -addressbook`

Answer (score 8):

You can find your answer [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=657920&sid=8bb8c9755cc4320884f5057bbcae3e9b)

> This one is about as counter-intuitive as it gets. The trick is that you don't delete auto-complete entries from the main Thunderbird window -- you delete them from the autocomplete cache as accessible from within a new email.
>
> - Turn auto-completion on
> - Open a new email
> - Within the email window, click the Contacts button (should create a pane at the left with the list of addresses)
> - Delete the entry you don't want.

I've done this successfully on my machine.